# What is Eclipse shortcut key to turn on feature that allows when pressing TAB key, for cursor to go to expected position?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

When I am typing code in Eclipse, i am using 'TAB' key to jump to expected position, highlighted with green cursor.

For example, if I am typing `System.out.println("Some text"|)`, when I am at position just after the word "text", that "vertical bar" key is highlighted green, so if I press 'TAB' key, my cursor will jump to that position. As expected.

Now, I know that if I press 'ESC', that green "vertical bar" will disappear, actually that proposing position feature is turned off. My question is which keyboard key turns this feature back on?

Comment: Once all place holders were removed then there is no way to get it back. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024622/whats-this-box-around-my-function-input/23054367#23054367) and edit your post explaining what exactly you want.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Thanks for answer. So, there is no way to turn place holders on, after they are turned off. That is exactly what I was trying to do - to return back place holders, after I have turned them off by pressing `Esc` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes IMHO there is no way to **turn on** place holders back after they disappear. However you can cycle through forward or backward these place holder by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> keys when they were **active**.

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024622/whats-this-box-around-my-function-input/23054367#23054367) for more details