# What's this box around my function input?

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I write an auto-completed function call and start typing something, a black rectangle is drawn around the input, like below:

[image]

Why does eclipse do this and how can I turn it off? I've looked the different editor settings but I haven't found anything that describes this behavior.

Comment: I can't confirm this, but I'mm pretty sure its telling you which argument you're typing in; you can use tab to go to the next one. It's just a quick way of filling in arguments when you auto-complete a function. The box goes away if you just click outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called place holder. Keep caret anywhere in between the class methods and inside the class body and type **public** and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and select **public_method** option. Then you will get a template looks like this:

[image]

Here **return_type** is covered with rectangle and highlighted this means you can type the return type as void, int etc and this will appear in this rectangle box.

Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to traverse next place holders i.e **name** is also covered with rectangle box. After typing the return type when you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> key you will jump to next place holder(i.e **name**).

You can go back to the previous place holder by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. Green color caret represent the end of place holders.

While you are in any place holder if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you will be directly taken to the end of the place holder(i.e green caret).

Check the template grammar for **public_method** template here `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editors > Templates`

It looks as

```
public ${return_type} ${name}(${}) {
    ${cursor}
}
```

You can edit this. If you remove **${cursor}** then green colour caret will not appear and so on.

You can turn if off by

1. Deleting template(Not recommended)
2. Editing template grammer
3. Or just by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key(Recommended)

Also check the grammar of **static_final** template. Here you will get the drop down menu along with rectangular box.