# Eclipse parameter dialog/hint when using functions in code

Tags: java, eclipse

By default In Eclipse when you use a function or create objects it helps with parameters like this:

[image: Eclipse content assist]

But once it's done, it'll never show up again. Is there any way to call this parameter helper on code that's already written when I point the cursor on the method?

The Image I uploaded only appears while writing code.

Comment: [Similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911106/make-eclipse-parameter-hints-visible-whenever-caret-is-inside-the-brackets). And yes, I agree that this would be helpful to know.

Comment: I didn't notice. Sorry for dat.

Comment: It's okay. There's no answer for this issue yet.

Comment: I always just backspace the parentheses and hit CTRL-space to bring up autocomplete again. I don't think there's a better way

Comment: To be honest, MSVS is better in term of this topic.

Comment: I know that it's an old issue, but in current Eclipse (Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)) and on macOS Sierra it is different to get the one that krzakov want and that what for example CTRL + Shift + Space shows up. With krzakov showing you can went throught the submitted params and it bolded the related part in the method. with CRTL + Shift +  Space it only shows the current selected (overwritten) method but does not highlight the current param-position

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ctrl + Shift + Space will do the trick. It is named Context information in Key preferences.

Answer (score 8):

Place the cursor just inside the left parenthesis and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on Mac) again; Eclipse will show [Content Assist](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-ContentAssist.htm&resultof=%22content%22%20%22assist%22%20) again.

[image]

Comment: It opens popup menu and not all arguments are visible

Answer (score 2):

When the mouse cursor is in the paranthesis, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. It will pop up menu (content assist). If you enter it, it will show the context information as it was at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

[JDT-Codemining](https://github.com/angelozerr/jdt-codemining) is a new project (as of Aug 2018) that supports parameter hints, along with many other features, such as:

```
General
    Show references
    Show implementations
    Show method parameter names
    Show method parameter types
    Show end statement
JUnit
    Show JUnit status
    Show JUnit run
    Show JUnit debug
Debugging
    Show variable values inline while debugging
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get place holders again once they disappeared. But you can get content assist help as said by @E-Riz

Check this answer [What is Eclipse shortcut key to turn on feature that allows when pressing TAB key, for cursor to go to expected position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014815/what-is-eclipse-shortcut-key-to-turn-on-feature-that-allows-when-pressing-tab-ke/23058596#23058596) and also this [What's this box around my function input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024622/whats-this-box-around-my-function-input/23054367#23054367)

Comment: Yep i know about it, but question was about something else, which is probably impossible.

Answer (score 0):

i was looking for the same shortcut and didn't find it ;
now i'm using 
*ctrl+Arrows to move between words 
*alt+shift+arrows to select the world and replace it